# apt-get install - where does it go?

Tags: java, apt

Just a basic question on this utility...  I did

`sudo apt-get install libhtmlparser-java`

And I would like to see the source I just downloaded.  On Linux (Ubuntu) where ought I look for this?

Comment: [askubuntu.com](http://askubuntu.com/) is part of StackExchange... It's perfect place for questions like this... :)

Comment: Wow.. Didn't know for that one.. +1

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
dpkg -L libhtmlparser-java
```

For the source:

```
apt-get source libhtmlparser-java
```

Comment: Perfect.  Dumb follow-up until I have time to actually learn pkg management tools better, how to find the source after apt-get source?

Comment: It's in a sub-directory the current directory (you'll also see the tarball and diff used to extract it). :)

Answer (score 1):

"apt-get install" installs compiled packages, not source. To see exactly what files were installed (and where they went), make sure your /etc/apt/sources.list has the "deb-src" equivalent entries for all of your "deb" entries (for the default entries you start with, this will be a matter of uncommenting the deb-src entries, if I recall correctly) and:

```
sudo apt-get install apt-file
sudo apt-file update
apt-file list libhtmlparser-java
```

As Matthew Flaschen notes above, you can get the source with "apt-get source", but that's like a wget -- it just puts it in your current directory. When I do this, I put it in /usr/local/src.

Edited: I should note that for installed packages, dpkg -L packagename will get you the list of files. You'd want apt-file to be able to list the files in uninstalled packages, or to search packages for a given file.